# What could cause UI updates via dispatch_async to fail when called from within a background queue block?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-mojave

Can anybody see a reason why this code would work fine to update UI:

```
__block NSDictionary *result = nil;
dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[[SomeService sharedInstance] doSomethingGreatWithReplyBlock:^(NSDictionary * response) {
    result = response;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self updateDisplay:result];
});
```

But this one won't?

```
__block NSDictionary *result = nil;
[[SomeService sharedInstance] doSomethingGreatWithReplyBlock:^(NSDictionary * response) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self updateDisplay:response];
    });
}];
```

Isn't this exactly the same? In the first example I'm waiting for the async operation to finish using a semaphore. Then dispatch_async on the main queue.

In the second one I'm calling dispatch_async (also on the main queue) directly from within the other block (which runs on some background queue). This one still calls the updateDisplay method fine - however it doesn't actually update the UI. It feels like some main thread update issue however [NSThread isMainThread] still returns true...

Is there any obvious difference I'm missing here? I'm pretty lost here and would appreciate any explanation. I have never observed such weird behavior before.

Comment: I doubt queues are the problem (turn on the main thread sanitizer to make sure). I suspect that either (a) `updateDisplay` is not actually run (put a breakpoint there to make sure it really is), or (b) there's a timing problem in what `updateDisplay` relies on. Make sure that nothing is `nil` in that method at the point that you get there (which is probably slightly different times for these two approaches). "Doesn't do anything" in ObjC 90% of the time means "something is nil." 9% of the time it means "you didn't actually call the thing you thought you did" and 1% it's something else.

Comment: Good point from @particleman. If this is run on the main thread, then this blocks the main thread, and that will dramatically change the timings (and is illegal, but still it can happen)

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is nil, every log is correct, all the values match but the UI still won't update ;-(

I'll check whether timing is an issue, thanks for that idea!

Comment: I think the point about running the semaphore code on the main-thread could lead me to the solution. Thank you very much for that hint, for some reason I didn't think about that.

Still not sure why it causes this issue, but that I'll figure out on Monday ;-)